STM32 HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback how to use it properly
I am developing an STM32H750 PCB for a future project and I am doing some tests on an STM32F103 to get familiar with STM32CubeIDE.
I am facing a problem with the HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback() function that doesn't work properly.
The flow is this:

Read the button state of a push button to switch an LED on or off. This works.
Write the LED status to external flash. This works.
Read the LED status on or off from flash and send it by UART. This works.
Here I have the HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback() function for which my goal is this:

When a message arrives from the UART I have 2 cases.
if message = uint8_t mess2[8] = {"A1B2C34D"};

Switch on the LED.

else if message = uint8_t mess3[8] = {"A1B20000"};

Switch off the LED.

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if (huart -> Instance == USART2)
    {
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2,rx_data,8);
        //rx_index = Size;
        //uint8_t rx_data[9];
        //Flash_Read(0,mess2,8);
        if (strstr((char *)rx_data,"ledonn")){
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_SET);
            HAL_Delay(100);
            uint8_t mess2[8] = {"A1B2C34D"};

            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,mess2,8,100);
            
            //void  NewStatus();
        }
        else if (strstr((char *)rx_data,"ledoff")){
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            HAL_Delay(100);
            uint8_t mess3[8] = {"A1B20000"};

            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,mess3,8,100);
        }


        //HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2,rx_data,9);
        //uint8_t statutled[8];
        //Flash_Read(0,statutled,8);
        // HAL_Delay(100);
        // HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,statutled,8,200);
    }
}

Note that I have tried to store in flash new records during the HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback().
It isn't working too.

HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback() is called from the context of the UART RX interrupt handler, so it's not a good idea to make calls to blocking functions like HAL_UART_Transmit() from there. You should rather use HAL_UART_Transmit_IT() to hand the transmission of these messages over to the HAL's UART TX interrupt handler, thus allowing HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback() to exit and return to your main code instead of being stuck in the UART RX interrupt.

You should probably also only "re-prime" the UART RX with the HAL_UART_Receive_IT() call after you've checked the contents of rx_data, not before. Which also leads me to ask - you are calling HAL_UART_Receive_IT() from your main code somewhere initially aren't you and not just here in HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback()? Because you're only going to get a HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback() call to happen after you've asked the HAL to initiate a RX operation using HAL_UART_Receive_IT().

The code shown makes little sense withou seeing the main code that initializes the UART reception to be able to even trigger this callback.
